# Python3 can not import requests after install

Tags: python-3.x

Installed requests using pip3. pip3 list shows requests installed. `which python3` and `which pip3` show the same location. However still:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
>>>
```

I'm on OS X by the way

Comment: Have you re-launched the python shell after running `pip3 install ...`? What does `pip3 freeze` look like?